# Замена каждого вхождения на символ

Tags: python

Есть большой объем текста(строка), в котором встречаются цифры в скобках и без. Необходимо заменить цифры в скобках на символы, можно и сами скобки,например, х.

```
Ввод: 1 Для начала огляжусь (99) подойду к двери (117).

Вывод:1 Для начала огляжусь хххх подойдук двери ххххх.
```

```
pagetext = re.sub('\([\d]*\)','x', pagetext)
```

Заменяет весь блок на один символ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо текста для замены можно указать функцию, это даст большую свободу действий

```py
pagetext = re.sub(r'\(\d+\)', lambda match: 'x' * len(match.group()), pagetext)
```